# What would be an efficient way to find peaks in an array, valeys in another array and then concatenate them in an alternating style?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

i have two arrays, Highs and Lows, i want to find the peaks on Highs, valleys on Lows and then concatenate them in an alternating way so that there ain't two or more peaks/valleys consecutivelly, for example:

```
Highs = [107165., 107095., 107000., 107045., 106980., 106940., 106890.,
         106740., 106565., 106615., 106375., 106440., 106445., 106290.,
         106245., 106270., 106075., 105990., 106260., 106395., 106315.,
         106080., 106180., 106305., 106265., 106180., 106360., 106260.,
         106110., 106070.]

Lows = [106815., 106845., 106905., 106920., 106850., 106850., 106565.,
        106460., 106380., 106305., 106250., 106280., 106155., 106035.,
        106055., 105960., 105915., 105875., 105760., 106110., 105945.,
        105820., 105865., 106095., 106020., 105925., 106045., 106020.,
        105925., 105880.]
```

Apply a gaussian filter to smoothen the data

```
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter1d
gauH = gaussian_filter1d(Highs, 1)
gauL = gaussian_filter1d(Lows, 1)
```

Find peaks on Highs and valleys on Lows

```
iCeils  = (np.diff(np.sign(np.diff(gauH))) < 0).nonzero()[0] + 1 # Ceils index 
iFloors = (np.diff(np.sign(np.diff(gauL))) > 0).nonzero()[0] + 1 # Floors index
```

Now i need to concatenate and sort them, find when there's more than one peak/valley in a row and remove the lower/higher from the array.
Currently im doing like this:

Assign 1 to peaks and 0 to valleys

```
iCeils = np.concatenate([np.reshape(iCeils, (len(iCeils), 1)), np.reshape(np.ones(len(iCeils)), 
(len(iCeils), 1))], axis = 1).astype(int)

iFloors = np.concatenate([np.reshape(iFloors, (len(iFloors), 1)), np.reshape(np.zeros(len(iFloors)), 
(len(iFloors), 1))], axis = 1).astype(int)
```

Concatenate both and sort in a pandas dataframe

```
iCF = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([iCeils, iFloors], axis = 0), columns = ['Val', 'kind']).sort_values(['Val'])
```

Which for context gives me something like this:

```
iCF = pd.DataFrame([[17,  0],
                    [19,  1],
                    [21,  0],
                    [25,  0],
                    [26,  1]], columns = ['Val', 'kind'])
```

There's 2 valleys in a row with values 21 and 25, Low[21] = 105820 < Low[25] = 105925, so remove 25 from dataframe and get this:

```
iCF = pd.DataFrame([[17,  0],
                    [19,  1],
                    [21,  0],
                    [26,  1]], columns = ['Val', 'kind'])
```

Now i could loop throught the entire dataframe and check if the column 'kind' has the same value consecutively and delete the highest valleys and lowest peaks, but im not sure a loop would be more efficient way, any suggestions?

Edit1, to become clearer, i want to remove the dots in blue circle
[image: Points in blue circles have to be removed from iCF]

Edit2, i misstyped which Val should be removed

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative using scipy.signal followed by a list comprehension.

EDIT: Replaced the test data by the entire dataset (25466 rows). The whole code takes 3.67 s ± 364 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each) to run on my machine, including all imports and plots.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
from collections import Counter

dataset=pd.read_csv('/path/to/WIN205.csv', delimiter = ':', header = 0)

Highs=np.array(dataset.High)

Lows=np.array(dataset.Low)

#find peaks by simple comparison of neighboring value
peaks, _ = find_peaks(Highs)
plt.plot(Highs,color='gray', zorder=1)

#invert Lows to transform
Lows_inv=Lows*(-1)
valleys, _ = find_peaks(Lows_inv)

#plot the results
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot(Highs,color='gray', zorder=1)
plt.scatter(peaks, Highs[peaks], color='red', marker='x', s=100, zorder=2)
plt.title('Peaks',fontsize=18)
plt.xlabel('Values (n°)',fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('Highs (?)',fontsize=15)
plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(Lows,color='gray', zorder=1)
plt.scatter(valleys, Lows[valleys], color='red', marker='x', s=100, zorder=2)
plt.title('Valleys',fontsize=18)
plt.xlabel('Values (n°)',fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('Lows (?)',fontsize=15)

#combine peaks and valleys
df_peaks=pd.DataFrame({'category':np.ones(len(peaks)), 'height': Highs[peaks]},index=peaks)
df_valleys=pd.DataFrame({'category':np.zeros(len(valleys)), 'height': Lows[valleys]}, index=valleys)
df_pv=pd.concat([df_peaks,df_valleys], sort=True).sort_index()

#split df by blocks of consecutive same categories 
df_pv['block'] = (df_pv.category.shift(1) != df_pv.category).astype(int).cumsum()

#count number of values in each block
blocks=Counter(df_pv['block'])

def filter_outputs(block_id, nb_vals):
    
    #work on blocks with consecutive same categories
    if nb_vals>1:
        
        df_block=df_pv[df_pv.block==block_id]
        
        #check if peak or valley block and keep max if peak, min if valley
        if df_block.category.iloc[0]==1:
            indxs_to_keep=[np.where(df_pv.height==np.nanmax(df_block.height))[0][0]]
        else:
            indxs_to_keep=[np.where(df_pv.height==np.nanmin(df_block.height))[0][0]]
    
    #keep other blocks unchanged
    else:
        
        indxs_to_keep=[np.where(df_pv.block==block_id)[0]]
            
    return indxs_to_keep

#find all indexes to keep
indxs_to_keep=[filter_outputs(block_id, nb_vals) for block_id, nb_vals in blocks.items()]

#and keep them!
df_pv_filtered=df_pv.reset_index().iloc[[val for sublist in indxs_to_keep for val in sublist]]
```

Comment: My dataset contains 25k values for now, but it'll grow bigger in the future.
For the solution, i think ill work on it, but im trying to figure out why it keeps 2 peaks in a row in the first values.

Comment: It also struggles when there's more than 2 peak/valleys in a row.

Comment: How/where can i share a file for you?

Comment: You could drop it on some cloud. Github could also work.

Comment: I shared the file on google drive, a pandas read to read it
pd.read_csv(directory, delimiter = ':', header = 0)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N069EGvIJh7GCw12Ef6X2PDjZVJS7F7b/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Let me known if you got the file.

Comment: Alright, im looking through the code, want to known what's going ong hehhe
when, checking if peak or valley to keep them, 
            indxs_to_keep=[np.where(df_pv==np.nanmax(df_block.height))[0][0]]
            indxs_to_keep=[np.where(df_pv.height==np.nanmin(df_block.height))[0][0]]

is it df_pv.height ==... on both checks, or the first one is only df_pv?

Comment: I realised it's 

indxs_to_keep=[np.where(df_pv.height==np.nanmax(df_block.height))[0][0]]
and it's working perfectly
thank you very much :)

Comment: Oups, indeed it should be df_pv.height! But it still finds the correct index, I'll edit! You're welcome!